# $firebaseAuth with AngularFire 2.0.1 and Firebase 3.0.5

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am trying to upgrade to Firebase 3 and AngularFire 2.

I have run `initializeApp` in the config phase of the app:

`let firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: config.fbSecret,
  authDomain: config.firebaseAuthDomain,
  databaseURL: config.firebaseBase
},
fbApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
let baseRef = firebase.database().ref()`

and then 'provided` the baseRef for injection into other modules(as I do in the old version):

`$provide.value('FirebaseBase', baseRef);`

so that I can inject `FirebaseBase` into a service module and use e.g. `FirebaseBase.child('profile')`.

That doesn't generate any errors, but I am getting this error in the console when the app runs:

`angular.js:4576 Uncaught Error: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp().`

There is no indication of where the error comes from, but I have some authentication code in the `run` phase:

`$firebaseAuth.$onAuthStateChanged(..`

and I'm guessing that it might come from there. I have tried to follow the migration guides but there doesn't seem to be any real-life example and it is not clear to me how the new AngularFire ties in with `firebase.initializeApp`.

Is there a sample app anywhere? Am I missing something?

Comment: You get this error when you call firebase.initializeApp() multiple times in the same app. You should only ever call it one time. Are you sure you are only running your config code once? Are you actually calling initializeApp() at some other place in your code? Can you update your answer to include your setup code?

Comment: It's an angular app. As far as I know the config can only run once at start up. The structure of the (working) app hasn't really changed. InitializeApp isn't run anywhere else in the client-side app. 

The message seems to suggest that the initializeApp hasn't been run at all, not that it has been run multiple times. Is that wrong? 

It's not really possible to post all of the setup code as there's quite a lot of it.

Comment: Ahh yeah, I misread that, sorry. It looks like your config code is not actually being run before you start using Firebase. Without seeing your setup code, I'm not sure how I can help you. Try to pare it down and you may find the problem yourself. Also, have you looked into using AngularFire (https://github.com/firebase/angularfire) to simplify using Angular and Firebase together?

Answer (score 2):

you need to call the initialization in the beginning of the `run` block in your angular code since you are trying to authorize in there, I made this mistake in a few of my earlier integrations of Firebase

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services', 'ngCordova'])

  .run(function ($ionicPlatform, FirebaseDB, $rootScope, $state) {

    FirebaseDB.initialize();

    // for authentication, managing the state if error..
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError',
      function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {

        // if the error is "NO USER" the go to login state
        if (error === "NO USER") {
          event.preventDefault();
          $state.go('login', {});
        }
      });

  })
```

in my firebaseService

```
  .factory('FirebaseDB', function ($q, $state, $timeout) {
    var instance, storageInstance, unsubscribe, currentUser = null
    var initialized = false

    return {
      initialize: function () {

        // Not initialized so... initialize Firebase
        var config = {
            //SET YOUR CONFIG BLOCK HERE
        };

        // initialize database and storage
        instance = firebase.initializeApp(config);
        storageInstance = firebase.storage();

        // listen for authentication event, dont start app until I 
        // get either true or false
        unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
          currentUser = user
          console.log("got user..", currentUser);
        })
      },
    }
  })
```

Comment: thanks was looking for the best practice for angular initialization. All documentation that i came across was putting it in the index.html. Where did get this info?

Comment: it is just an approach we use on all of our apps, just did not seem right to place this in the index.html

Answer (score -3):

If you put it in the Run phrase it will fix it.

Comment: This answer is unclear and should be further developed.  Please explain the answer in a way that helps all users, not just the user who asked the question.